# Modules with null or empty names are not supported. Ninject

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

In our MVC project, we are extensively using Ninject. For an unknown reason, StandardKernel started to throw NotSupportedException with message "Modules with null or empty names are not supported". Here's the code:

```
        var _kernel = new StandardKernel(); // <-- this line throws exception
        _kernel.Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(x =>
            {
                 // some code...
            }).InSingletonScope();
        _kernel.Bind<IAppDomainSetup>().To<AppDomainSetup>();
```

anyone has any idea what could be wrong? Thanks.

P.S. here's nuget config to see assembly versions

```
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.0.1.10" targetFramework="net45" />  
  <package id="Ninject.MVC3" version="3.0.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />   
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.0.0.7" targetFramework="net45" />
```

and here's stacktrace

```
  at Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable`1 m) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 207
   at Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable`1 assemblies) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 245
   at Ninject.Modules.CompiledModuleLoaderPlugin.LoadModules(IEnumerable`1 filenames) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Modules\CompiledModuleLoaderPlugin.cs:line 82
   at Ninject.Modules.ModuleLoader.LoadModules(IEnumerable`1 patterns) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Modules\ModuleLoader.cs:line 60
   at Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable`1 filePatterns) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 236
   at Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(IComponentContainer components, INinjectSettings settings, INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 97
   at Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 57
   at Ninject.StandardKernel..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\StandardKernel.cs:line 46
   at TradeNet.Web.MvcApplication.CreateKernel() in c:\Users\dpopiashvili.DEA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TradeNet\TradeNet.Web\Global.asax.cs:line 65
   at Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\Bootstrapper.cs:line 50
   at Ninject.Web.Common.NinjectHttpApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\NinjectHttpApplication.cs:line 80
```

Comment: So it means that the same code worked before? What have you changed? Do you have some custom `NinjectModule` which overrides the Name property?

Comment: no, I don't have any, but i'm using Ninject.Web.Common library in my project, I guess it should have some modules in use internally...

Comment: Ok, but you haven't answered the what have you change part... Also
please check your `bin` folder and look for the files: `"Ninject.Extensions.*.dll"` and `"Ninject.Web.*.dll"`. Can you post the list of files which matches this scheme?

Comment: Thanks nemesv. We didn't change kernel creation part. nor did we upgrade ninject or it's libraries to a newer version. The reason why it started to throw this exception is a puzzle for me. I checked bin folder, there is Ninject.dll, Ninject.Web.Mvc.dll, and Ninject.Web.Common.dll

Comment: Maybe the .net version changed? Have you installed VS2013 latelly? Does it only happen on one machine or you can repro on multiple machine? Have you tried clean/rebuild the solution? Restart the machine?

Comment: No I didn't instal vs2013. It happens on multiple machines... :(

Comment: Please try to repro this issue in a newly created MVC project! Maybe you will find out what is causing the problem, if no then upload the repro project somewhere.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `var _kernel = new StandardKernel();` line with `var _kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false }, new MvcModule());`?

Comment: @nemesv what magic did you trick me into? :) I don't know why but I think it worked. Could you please post your comment as answer (with little explanation what we did if you don't mind) so I can mark it as answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a `StandardKernel` if the `LoadExtensions` proerty is `true` (this is the default value) of the `NinjectSettings` class then Ninject will scan the application directory to load modules from the extensions `dll`.

By default it searches the following patterns:

```
"Ninject.Extensions.*.dll",
"Ninject.Web*.dll"
```

and loads all the `INinjectModule` implementation from the found dlls.

In your case this automatic module loading process throwing the exception because one of the loaded module's `Name` property is `null`.

This can happen in two cases:

- Ninject loaded a module which explicitly implemented the  `INinjectModule` and returned `null` as the name or a module which derived from `NinjectModule` but overridden the default `Name` implementation and returned `null`
- Or the default `Name` implementation in the `NinjectModule` returned `null`... however this is how the [source code](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Modules/NinjectModule.cs#L55-L58) of the `Name` look like:

  ```
  public virtual string Name
  {
       get { return GetType().FullName; }
  }
  ```

  so it only returns `null` if the [Type.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `null` which can happen [in very rare cases.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2006/02/17/534480.aspx)

So to solve your problem you need to find out which extension/module has the `Name` null:

- you can check the loaded Ninject/Extension dlls with [fusion log](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) to make sure that you are loading the correct ones
- you can try-catch the `new StandardKernel()` and log out the loaded modules with

  ```
   try
   {
       _kernel = new StandardKernel();
   }
   catch
   {
      var modules =
          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
              .SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes()
              .Where(t => typeof(INinjectModule).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
              .ToArray();
   }
  ```

Until you find out which `INinjectModule` causing the problem you can turn off the automatic extension loading and manually load the `MvcModule` with

```
var _kernel = new StandardKernel(
     new NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false }, new MvcModule());
```